# Plotting using gnuplot.py

Tags: python, gnuplot

Below is my code to simulate4 my circuit's netlist using Xyce and then take the output file and plot it using gnuplot. I only want to ask when I remove the last line "subprocess.call('gnuplot')" the plotting doesn't work. So, I had to add it,no idea why? However, now when I add this line and the code reaches it it opens gnuplot in the command line and I can't exit from gnuplot automatically. SO my questions are why does it have to be there? and how to exit from gnuplot automatically i.e. using a command in the code to continue the rest of my code.
Thanks

```
!/usr/bin/env python

#Plotting Output File

from numpy import *

import subprocess

import Gnuplot

subprocess.call(['./Xyce','mscmemory_cell.cir'])

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()

g.plot(Gnuplot.File('mscmemory_cell.cir.prn', using=(2,3), with_= "lines"))

subprocess.call('gnuplot')
```

Comment: If you used numpy, why not use matplotlib?

Comment: I tried using matplotlib and didn't succeed as the first row in my data files contains the titles for the columns. Also, I couldn't choose which columns to plot. SO, if you can help me with that it would be good.